# How we can create a Login page which redirects according to user role in android if using mysql database and php?

Tags: android

My project is basically that I want to check if user is student or teacher according to that redirection to different page will happen,if student then different page for teacher different page.
But the problem is I want to check while login in so that I am doing that with the help of php and mysql database so how should I check if user is student or teacher in php file itself and then take that result to the postexecute() function.
**I HAVE DATABASE NAME TRACKATTENDANCE TABLE NAME LOGIN CONTAINS USERNAME ,PASSWORD AND USER_TYPE.**
Main Activity =

```
public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = Username.getText().toString();
    String password = Password.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";

    BackgroundWork backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWork(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}
```

Backgroundwork

This a backgroundwork class login purpose.

```
public class BackgroundWork extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>    
{
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    BackgroundWork (Context ctx) {
        //context = ctx;
        this.context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type= params[0];
        String login_url ="http://trackattendance.org/login.php";

        if(type.equals("login.php")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                String user_role=params[3];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("user_role","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_role,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        ProgressDialog progressdialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        progressdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply, just use `switch()` or `if-else`, and check in your DB is it teacher or student then open which activity you want.

Comment: Actually my problem is how should compare the database value teacher or student and where in the code.

Comment: Firstly, create an key in your DB that indicate either user is teacher or student. Then fetch it from your DB, while user is trying to login. If returned key from teacher or student, open activity according to it.